# How to place images using jQuery masonry plugin to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to create a simple image gallery for images of varying height/width and ran into masonry in search of a plugin that does something like that.

I was trying to do a mockup of this based on other example of empty box layout on masonry but I can't figure out how you would do this to place image in these boxes.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/kz2b79s3/
```

This is how I organized one tile:

```
 <div class="item"> <img src="https://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-001.jpg"> </div>
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the image is 'bleeding' out instead of being contained in the box. Must have missed something silly here.

Comment: just added an answer for you  @zigzag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just missing a `css` class that adjusts the image according to its parent container

```
.item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
```

see example below

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 100
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #CCC;
}

.item.w2 {
  width: 130px;
}

.item.h2 {
  height: 130px;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"> <img src="https://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-001.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7720/night-animal-dog-pet.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/356378/pexels-photo-356378.jpeg"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://pixabay.com/photo-1210559/"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Muhammad. Appreciate it. Btw, how do I remove the random gaps between 'tiles'. Here is the updated version. http://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/kz2b79s3/2/

Comment: you ca use the `percentPosition` and  `class` for `columnWidth` for a responsive layout, see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpeg) , more over if you just want to reduce the width keeping the same layout you can reduce the `columnWidth` option value, but you need to look into the `css` you are using you should follow the same set of CSS rules as given in the codepen I provided you @zigzag

Comment: do select the answer as correct one if it helped you @zigzag